# How Do i Unit Test Form Submission In React-Redux Components using Mocha

Tags: reactjs, mocha.js, sinon, redux, chai

I have a Html Form in my React Components Render Method.
I am Using Mocha chai sinon, how do I test the form submission functionality?
Can Someone point to an Example ?

Comment: http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/WritingTests.html Here ya go!

Comment: Thanks  @HenrikAndersson but I have already read that, i need to test my form component and i as looking for something which can help me test that.

Answer (score 2):

I created a project to show how I unit test and do integration tests with Redux-Form. Your question is not about redux-form specifically, but the project will show you how to isolate your component from redux for unit testing, as well as simple integration tests. The tests include testing submission functionality.

The project is at https://github.com/tylercollier/redux-form-test.